# Terminology for unipotent-like representations in infinite dimensions

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, terminology

Let $G$ be a discrete group and let $V$ be a vector space over a field of characteristic $0$ upon which $G$ acts linearly.  I'm looking for the right terminology for the following situation: for all $g \in G$, there exists a linear map $n_g\colon V \rightarrow V$ that is nilpotent in the sense that some finite power of $n_g$ is $0$ such that $g$ acts on $V$ as ${\operatorname{id}} + n_g$.  It is clear that this should be called a unipotent representation, and if $V$ is finite-dimensional then all unipotent representations are of this form.  But is it right to use this as the definition of a unipotent representation if $V$ is infinite-dimensional?  There are other things that should also probably be called unipotent (e.g. if $n_g$ is only required to be "locally nilpotent" in the sense that for all $v \in V$, there is some power of $n_g$ that takes $v$ to $0$).  What term should I use?

Comment: Since the terminology is not clearly wrong but is confusing, I think that the simplest answer is:  call it unipotent as you suggest, but emphasise explicitly that you mean $n_g$ to be "uniformly, not just locally, nilpotent".  (Although that might suggest uniformity in $g$, so I would say to separate it:  first define what it means for a single operator to be "uniformly unipotent" or whatever, then require that your $G$ act by such operators.)

Comment: I think that the term in the title, namely ``unipotent-like representation'', is better.

Comment: @user148212: The problem with the phrase "unipotent-like" is that it suggests that these are not unipotent, but only share some features with unipotent representations.

Comment: @LSpice: That will be what I do if I don't find a more standard term.

Comment: If you can believe Wikipedia in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unipotent they call an element r of a ring unipotent if r-1 is nilpotent. So by their convention you would be fine.  But I don't know how standard that is.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: My understanding is that in representation theory it is common to say that a linear map unipotent if all of its (generalized) eigenvalues are $1$ and a representation is unipotent if all of its associated linear maps are unipotent.  This is consistent with the ring-theoretic terminology in finite dimensions, but not in infinite dimensions, where there are many possible definitions (including ones more general than the two I suggested in my question).

Comment: @Linda, I agree.  But your suggested terminology is consistent with what Wikipedia calls unipotent in ring theory but I agree there are other reasonable choices